# How to integrate Sphinx Makefile into existing project Makefile?

Tags: python, makefile, python-sphinx

I have an existing project with the following directory structure:

```
docs/
    conf.py
    Makefile
    index.rst
    documentation-foo.rst
    documentation-bar.rst
src/
    ...code...
common.mk
Makefile
README.rst
```

In the root of the repository, the `Makefile` contains various useful commands related to making, testing, packaging, and deploying the code. Likewise, `common.mk` includes a check to make sure the user has several utility programs available on their system (e.g., `jq` for manipulating/displaying JSON) that cannot be installed with `pip`. I can issue commands like `make lint` or `make test` and those are defined in that Makefile. (The top of the `Makefile` also has an `include common.mk`, see below for Makefile contents.)

In the `docs/` folder, the `Makefile` is automatically generated by Sphinx. This Makefile is standalone and is totally independent of the Makefile or common.mk files in the root of the repository. I can issue commands like `make html` and it will use Sphinx to generate the documentation in HTML format.

Contents of (root) **/Makefile**:

```
include common.mk

clean:
    ...

lint:
    ...

test:
    ....
```

Contents of (root) **/common.mk**:

```
ifeq ($(shell which jq),)
$(error Please install jq using "apt-get install jq" or "brew install jq")
endif
```

Contents of (sphinx) **/docs/Makefile**:

```
# Minimal makefile for Sphinx documentation
SPHINXOPTS    ?=
SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build
...
```

**My primary question is this: how can I incorporate the rules from the sphinx Makefile at `/docs/Makefile` so that they are available from the root level `/Makefile`?**

For example, to make HTML documentation, I currently have to `cd docs && make html` from the root of the repo, but I would like to be able to run `make html` from the root of the repo and have the Makefile in the root of the repo resolve the target to the `html` target defined in `docs/Makefile` and use the rule defined in that Makefile.

Second, related question: if I have commands in `docs/Makefile` that have relative paths, must the paths be updated to be relative to the location where the `make` command is being run (the root of the repo instead of `docs/`), or does `make` resolve relative links to be relative to the Makefile's location in `docs/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [recursive make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html):

```
html:
    $(MAKE) -C docs html
```

Some people strongly dislike recursive make. You can read [the arguments against it](http://www.real-linux.org.uk/recursivemake.pdf), but I don't believe they apply to your use of make, since you're not trying to express dependencies.